# Can "sich" be used with "mit"?

Tags: grammatical-case

*"Er führte ein lilafarbenes Fahrrad mit sich."*

I'm pretty sure that the dative comes after "mit". And the the dative form for "er" is "ihm", right?

God, I'm around B1 level right now but this still confuses me. Is that bad?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the dativ comes with "mit".

However in this case you don't have:

> mit einem Fahrrad

... but you have the fixed expression you'll find in a dictionary:

> *etwas (Akkusativ)* mit sich führen

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he was wondering why "sich" isn't in the dative case (which it is, as other answers point out), not why "ein lilafarbenes Fahrrad" isn't in the dative case.

Comment: @sgf Correct. And the answer is: Because the word "mit" does not apply to the word "Fahrrad", but to the word "sich". Sorry if my answer was not clear in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in saying that the dative form of *er* is *ihm*.

But: if the subject and the object of the sentence refer to the same person/thing, the *ihm/ihr* changes into *sich*.

In this case, *mit sich führen* is a single verb consisting of several words, so it wouldn't make sense to say **er führte ein Fahrrad mit ihm*.

With other verbs, both *ihm* and *sich* are possible, with different meaning.

> - Er lieh *sich* ein Auto. — He rented a car.
> - Er lieh *ihm* ein Auto. — He lended him a car. (two different people involved)

Answer (score 1):

"mit" is a **preposition**, which literally means "put before". It comes *before* the word that it governs - in this case "sich". And to be sure, "sich" is a dative form (the reflexive dative and accusative are both "sich").

"Er" is simply a subject. Subjects are never inflected away from the nominative no matter what constructions the main clause contains.